# QSSTV death march

Tags: dell, ham-radio

I'm attempting to run the Amateur (ham) radio program [qsstv](http://users.telenet.be/on4qz/qsstv/manual/index.html) on Ubuntu 19.10, on a new Dell PC, Optiplex 5055  with an AMD PRO A10-9700 R7 CPU with 10 compute cores (4C+6G) and 8GB RAM. 
swapon
NAME      TYPE       SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda5 partition 14.9G   4M   -2
free 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        7082736     2973652      491932       76956     3617152     3732324
Swap:      15625212        4096    15621116

lscpu 
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      21
Model:                           101
Model name:                      AMD PRO A10-9700 R7, 10 COMPUTE CORES 4C+6G
Stepping:                        1
Frequency boost:                 enabled
CPU MHz:                         1396.819
CPU max MHz:                     3500.0000
CPU min MHz:                     1400.0000
BogoMIPS:                        6986.46
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       64 KiB
L1i cache:                       192 KiB
L2 cache:                        2 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled v
                                 ia prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user
                                  pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full AMD retpoline, IBPB conditiona
                                 l, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr
                                 r pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse s
                                 se2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtsc
                                 p lm constant_tsc rep_good acc_power nopl nonst
                                 op_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulq
                                 dq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe p
                                 opcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm
                                  extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnow
                                 prefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce n
                                 odeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb b
                                 pext ptsc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate ssbd ibpb vmmcal
                                 l fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 xsaveopt arat np
                                 t lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean 
                                 flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthresho
                                 ld avic vgif overflow_recov

Every step of the way in this program, from the opening splash screen to clicking on different tabs and menu options in the program, there is a long 60-120 second wait before anything happens. Many other programs run like the wind on this PC, so I'm not sure what is going on here.

I tried to just [mv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mv.1.html) the /home/user/sstv dir, and start with a new config, no luck.
If I run this in a windows while going into the config menu, and attempting to restart and cat interface:

sudo journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-04-16 01:30:53 CDT. --
Apr 22 19:30:01 hamshack CRON[4055]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 22 19:32:53 hamshack systemd[1](http://users.telenet.be/on4qz/qsstv/manual/index.html): Started Run anacron jobs.
Apr 22 19:32:53 hamshack anacron[4080]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2020-04-22
Apr 22 19:32:53 hamshack anacron[4080]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Apr 22 19:32:53 hamshack systemd[1](http://users.telenet.be/on4qz/qsstv/manual/index.html): anacron.service: Succeeded.
Apr 22 19:37:45 hamshack sudo[4169]:     john : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/john ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lshw
Apr 22 19:37:45 hamshack sudo[4169]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 22 19:37:48 hamshack sudo[4169]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 22 19:39:21 hamshack sudo[4197]:     john : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/john ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -f
Apr 22 19:39:21 hamshack sudo[4197]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

Comment: OM, the CPU is not very important here; the chipset is much more relevant. What's the model number of the PC? How does the camera interface, by USB or into a PCie card? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: In a separate terminal window,  `sudo journalctl -f` as you run `qsstv` may help. How much swap space do you have? `free;man mkswap; man swapon; man free`.